# How to use timeout for this nested Bash script?

Tags: bash, terminal, parallel-processing, timeout, mpi

I wrote the following bash script, which works all right, apart from some random moments when it freezes completely and doesn't evolve further past a certain value of `a0`

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4

N_SIM=15000
N_NODE=1

for ((i = 1; i <= $N_SIM; i++))
do
    index=$((i))
    a0=$(awk "NR==${index} { print \$2 }" Intensity_Wcm2_versus_a0_10_20_10_25_range.txt)
    dirname="a0_${a0}"
    if [ -d "${dirname}" ]; then
        cd -P -- "${dirname}" # enter the directory because it exists already
        if [ -f "ParticleBinning0.h5" ]; then # move to next directory because the sim has been already done and results are there
            cd ..
            echo ${a0}
            echo We move to the next directory because ParticleBinning0.h exists in this one already.
            continue 1
        else
            awk -v s="a0=${a0}" 'NR==6 {print s} 1 {print}' ../namelist_for_smilei.py > namelist_for_smilei_a0included.py
            echo ${a0}
            mpirun -n 1 ../smilei namelist_for_smilei_a0included.py 2&> smilei.log
            cd ..
        fi
    else
        mkdir -p $dirname
        cd $dirname
        awk -v s="a0=${a0}" 'NR==6 {print s} 1 {print}' ../namelist_for_smilei.py > namelist_for_smilei_a0included.py
        echo ${a0}
        mpirun -n 1 ../smilei namelist_for_smilei_a0included.py 2&> smilei.log 
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

I need to let this to run for 12 hours or so in order for it to complete all the 15,000 simulations.

One `mpirun -n 1 ../smilei namelist_for_smilei.py 2&> smilei.log` command takes 4 seconds to run on average.

Sometimes it just stops at one value of `a0` and the last printed value of `a0` on the screen is say `a0_12.032131`.
And it stays like this, stays like this, for no reason.
There's no output being written in the `smilei.log` from that particularly faulty `a0_12.032131` folder.
So I don't know what has happened with this particular value of `a0`.
Any value of `a0` is not particularly important, I can live without the computations for that 1 particular value of `a0`.

I have tried to use the timeout utility in Ubuntu to somehow make it advance past any value of a0 which takes more than 2 mins to run. If it takes more than that to run, it clearly failed and stops the whole process running forwards.

It is beyond my capabilities to write such a script.

How shall a template look like for my particular pipeline?

Thank you!

Comment: I've never used `mpirun` so excuse me if this is silly question: `-n 1` seems to mean that you want to run one process. Is that different than just removing `mpirun -n 1` and just run the `../smileii` program without `mpirun`? Or is the `../smileii` program instrumented in some way that it requires `mpirun`? To put it another way: Where does it do things in parallel?

Comment: Yes, quite useless I believe as well, however it does not do any significant harm, if it does. I didn't write the code SMILEI: https://smileipic.github.io/Smilei/index.html.  , so I'm not aware of the underlying mechanics. I usually run it this way because sometimes I write mpirun -n 2, sometimes mpirun -n 1, and change the number of threads at the beginning of the script accordingly to the 4 cores = OpenMP * MPIprocs, from my laptop, just to get the maximum performance possible by testing these commands. The question is more of a bash question, rather than mpirun one I believe.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this `mpirun` program is hanging. As you said you could use the `timeout` utility to terminate its execution after a reasonable amount of time has passed:

```
timeout --signal INT 2m mpirun...
```

Depending on how `mpirun` handles signals it may be necessary to use KILL instead of INT to terminate the process.